# Какова архитектура для связки двух API?

Tags: python, api

Самостоятельно учу Python, чтобы автоматизировать работу. Мне нужно создать скрипт, который в случае создания сделки в CRM будет собирать данные об этой сделке, обрабатывать их и отправлять на сервис маркетинговой аналитики. Для этого я собираюсь использовать API этих двух сервисов.

Вопрос в том, как это должно выглядеть архитектурно? Мой скрипт должен размещаться на сервере? Он должен быть постоянно запущен или можно организовать его вызов по триггеру? Или мне нужно создать новое API, которое будет мостом между этими сервисами?

Я не прошу читать мне лекцию по этой теме, конечно же, но полагаю что задача тривиальная и либо есть материалы и темы, которые помогут мне с ее решением, либо какое-то короткое описание, по-типу: "Да, пиши API".

Большое спасибо тем, кто уделит мне время.

Comment: Можно ли там что то вызывать и как от должен быть запущен решается исключительно вашей CRM что она позволяет делать, то и надо использовать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Правильно ли понимаю, что использовать скрипт для этого сценария не рационально и стоит использовать внутренние инструменты СРМ-ки?

Comment: Вообще очень от многого зависит какую архитектуру выбрать. Например, если у вас будет много таких запросов, а работают они долго, то тогда лучше в какую-то шину сообщений типа `RabbitMQ` и т.п. помещать запрос, а отдельно висящий ваш сервис пусть эту очередь сообщений потом разгребает и делает нужное дело. А если там мало и быстро, то прям внутри `CRM` можно какой-то код написать и пусть он исполняется.

Comment: @Vadym Если даже внутренних инструментов в CRM нет, то надо посмотреть как нужный функционал к ней доабвить. Иначе внешнему скрипту придется скорее всего по API полностью снимать слепок всех данных CRM, а потом через какое время брать следующий слепок, сравнивать с предыдущим и на основе разницы уже что то там куда то отправлять. Это сложно и не рационально